# Automation Web "Base Cases"?

Tags: automated-testing

So I have a bit of a problem, since im the only QA at my company and I have many Web based projects going on right now it's very difficult to Automate DURING iterations (just due to manpower).

So what i've been doing it automating test cases (for regression mainly) once the product is stable. Sort of as a (check this during build) when a new feature is added or bugfix is done.

However I'd like to automate more, but automating everything is honestly just not possible due to time/workload. However for a website im trying to come up with some "easy" base cases? Things that are easy to write and test the basics of a website but don't go into crazy detail (IE time that I don't have to write detailed automated test cases).

So far to me I have some ideas for things such as:

- Logging In
- Hitting "Main" links on the webpage and checking the content after
- Logging Out
- Getting to the Main homepage of course
- Maybe doing 1 main feature of the site (such as putting an item in your cart for a store for instance).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation testing is never meant to be with 100% coverage. Even during development, it takes a lot of effort to keep automated scripts up to date. For this purpose is good to make agreement with development, that unique ID's will be added to each significant object.

It is hard to give some advice to your project as we do not know anything about it. But if you doubt, what part/use case to test first, you can do a little analysis based on:

- **Business value** of the Use case - you will count points for how much will this use case bring to the company if it is working.
- **Risk analysis** of each Use case - you will count points for each component which could go wrong, each subsystem (its complexity, supplier and subsystem reliability, etc.) or integration/interface (dtto) each component used on your web (dtto).
- **Own code complexity** of each Use case - you will ask developers for priorities. They will be able to tell you priorities based on their code complexity. You will count extra points for "unsure/unclear" things.

+updated

- **Estimated count of executions** of each Use case per period. More often executed use cases should be automated first.

Combined score will tell you which  use cases should go first and you can just work top-down in never-ending test cycle.

Additionally, you can write automated tests in different depth of the Test case. You can do your own, but it could be for example:

- Record-play test case (if the tool allows it)
- Click trough to the UseCase page (page present)
- Click trough end to end functionality (business case done and result page present)
- GUI check of the Use Case (all objects on the page present)
- GUI check of all objects (details/texts correctness and results)
- Persistence checks (data on one page should result in other data on other page)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Uses cases which must be automated for a website are -

- Use cases which require the user to manually insert a lot of data on forms.
- Edge cases or cases with critical functionality
- Testing on different software/hardware platforms
- Simulate large number of users
- Repetitive steps
- Calculations
- Data is conditionally displayed on page based on any selections
- Log in after registration process
- Add/Edit/Delete functionality
- Any critical validations (date, price fields)
- Any important reports

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dee on prioritizing your test creation based on business value and risk.

I have found value in creating a test api/endpoint to check the back-end connections of a site.

For example, a http://myWebsite.com/api/test endpoint would be hit hourly to verify a suite of simple self-diagnostic tests.

- DB connections
- simple add/delete
- connection responses
- more complicated UI independent tests

Just make sure you secure it appropriately :)